# WMI query listening for target failure in windows 8 file history?

Tags: wmi

I need to listen for an event if any target failure (target not found, remove LAN cable) happened in windows 8 file history.

I have tried listening to file history service (fhsvc) changes, when a target failure occurs with the follwing query:

"Select * from InstanceModificationEvent Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Service' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'fhsvc'".

But event is not getting triggered for this.

Also I was looking for the registry changes after target failure. But nothing get changes.

Please help me how to achieve this using WMI query when backup target failure happens.

Thanks.